# how to display online vs. in-store pricing?

Tags: e-commerce, pricing

i'm currently working on enhancing the purchase flow on a project, and it has been requested to display **in-store pricing** with the online pricing on products.

any recommendations or examples online that feature in-store pricing?

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: My assumption is online prices are always cheaper with discounts and offers compared to in-store prices as it involves maintenance. Why do you want to display both prices?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: you want to display offline prices in an online store to show that online purchases are cheaper and therefore more attractive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution!
I may not have been entirely clear in my question above.

I decided to show the amount of **savings** you get for purchasing online *(if any)* compared to buying in store.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Somthing like this could work.[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer really depends on what the products are, and your business objectives. I would be wary of using icons on their own - all but a handful of icons can easily be misinterpreted without labels, and can have different meaning in different cultures.

Here are some things that may affect the final outcome:

- Do you want to drive more people to buy online vs. in store?
- Do you offer a click and collect service, and if so, does this affect the final price?
- Does the online price include shipping/delivery costs (assuming you are selling physical items)?
- Have you considered the potential drawbacks of offering two different prices? (either in potential user confusion, or driving them to seek the same item elsewhere)

All of these things could influence the way you display the prices in one way or another. If your goal is to promote the online price over the instore price, then it's best to use clear, unambiguous labels as a starting point. You can support this using different visual treatments - colour, hierarchy, typography or iconography - to emphasise the differences.

In this example, Amazon uses hierarchy and colour to highlight the Kindle version over the printed version of its books. In this, their objectives are apparent - they want to sell a Kindle version over the printed version, and this is clearly reflected in the way the choices are presented to the user.

[image: Amazon displaying book prices]